# Why do we frequently see movie characters watching very old black and white movies?

Tags: cinematography

I couldn't help but notice that in many relatively new movies starting from 2000s, movie characters are very frequently shown watching extremely old black and white TV shows or movies rather than choosing in-line with the portrayed time frame programs or movies. I can understand occasional choices but it seems to be happening way too often and be rather a director's choice.

What may be a reason for such choice?

Comment: *"...many relatively new movies starting from 2000s, movie characters are very frequently shown watching extremely old black and white TV shows or movies."* - I dispute this premise. That encompasses thousands of movies over 16+ years. You might want to narrow the scope of the question.

Comment: Perhaps a legal issue? If you show a film in a film, you must check the copyright. For films older 70 years (1947) the copyright is run out (for details and correctness, ask a lawyer :) )

Comment: @knut a very interesting theory!

Comment: @Paulie_D I was about to ask exact same question. He is not the only one noticing this trend.

Comment: It's still way too broad. I'm sure there's a narrower question in there but i don't think so yet. Perhaps narrow it to specific *types* of movies or stories...but even then it's not really clear. Are we talking about the choice of a black and white film because of the color / age / genre? It's not likely that the film is being shown for **no reason** regardless of what film is being screened.

Comment: @Paulie_D from top of my head, watch a few seasons of X-Files (1993-???) although a bit earlier than 2000's yet every other episode has black and white, at least 40 year old movies being played on characters' TVs.

Comment: @sonne Not sure how that fits this question but what is being shown on the characters' TVs?. Is it possible it relates to the episode or the characters preferred watching? Mulder likes old SF movies about aliens as I recall.

Comment: @Paulie_D I am sure Scully and Skinner do not ;)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confirmation_bias

Comment: I expect its a form of writer's anachronism.  Sort of like how sitcoms in the 90s were littered with pop-culture references from the 60s & 70s.  Dialogue that the characters who are speaking it would logically be too young to remember - but the writers who wrote the script are old enough to.  Same thing here - the writers are picking background shows *they remember* and find appropriate, but which the characters depicted might be too young to care about.

Comment: While I see some insightful responses here, I also notice quite few downvotes. Can we please justify those or make some attempt to suggest a better wording and scoping of this question.

Answer (score 4):

@knut in the comments is correct. The licensing fees for showing clips from modern shows can be ridiculously high.

As a related example, I have a friend who is a feature film producer and wanted to use a song from the 1920s in her film. The licensing fees were in the high 10s to low 100s of thousands of dollars for a song that you would probably recognize but wouldn't consider popular even in your grandparents day. (I'm old, and my grandparents were born in the late 1910s to early 1920s. They died decades ago and they likely would have heard it on the radio as kids had they been able to afford one at the time.)

It's the same with movie and TV clips. The costs are exorbitant and I'm told often rights holders are very touchy about the context and being associated with other media that may or may not draw associations between their work and the new work from viewers.